# MySQLi multi_query() curiosity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Can someone explain me what does mysqli `multi_query()` is being used for? I don't understand wether a simple MySQLi query supports multimle statements or am I forced to use `multi_query()` in order to do a query like this:

```
   SET @row:=0;
   SELECT * FROM (
       select id,
       @row:=@row+1 AS `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `points` <= 63 ORDER BY `points` DESC
   ) AS number
   WHERE id = 1
```

I'm asking this becuase running `$mysqli->query(ABOVE_STATEMENT)` returns me a syntax error .. even though running the same statement in phpMyAdmin (set using mysqli extension) it succesfully returns the needed data.

Comment: phpmyadmin parses the SQL before sending it to the server IIRC. as those are two queries (separated by the semicolon `;`), it phpmyadmin executes two queries for you (with the same connection). You can easily try that as well your own with the mysql commandline client - if you're interested to explore this a bit on your own as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use multi_query to do that. The `@row` variable keeps its value for your whole session (i.e. until you disconnect from MySQL).

You may submit the `SET` statement and the `SELECT` statement as separate queries.

```
$mysqli->query("SET @row:=0");
$mysqli->query("SELECT * ... ");
```

There are no good reasons to use multi-query. [There are good reasons not to use multi-query.](http://xkcd.com/327/)

If someone tells you that it's more efficient to use multi-query because "one round trip is faster than two," tell them to show you a benchmark that proves it. Then tell them that you're not planning on running a thousand queries in one PHP request, because that's what it would take for the difference in performance to have any significant impact.

Comment: Definitely not disagreeing, but I think the crux of the question is that OP is most likely attempting to issue that as a single command, not two. So maybe just clarify that issuing two commands would be required.

Comment: technically, you do. there's 2 statements in that sample query (`set` and `select`). mysql's underlying php driver doesn't allow multiple statements in a single query() call as a basic coarse anti-injection defense mechanism. the multi query does some basic client-side parsing to separate the individual statements and fire them off as single statements.

Comment: @MarcB, mysqli has a function [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query), which enables the multi-query property and submits a semicolon-separated string of queries to the underlying C API call [mysql_real_query()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-query.html).

Comment: @BillKarwin isn't `exec()` method for PDO only ? I've looked a bit if it is for MySQLi and there's no `exec` method but `executed`

Comment: @edduvs, d'ohh you're right. My bad. I've edited the above to correct it. MySQLi's statement object does have an execute() method.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my code and this works flawlessly. All I needed to know was that using `SET` to creat a variable will make it available though the entire existence of that connection. Thank you very much, I know my english is quite bad, hope that I've expressed myself correctly previously.

Comment: @edduvs, LOL you have expressed yourself very well. I find nothing bad about your english, it's just about the same as any American would write! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

multi_query is if you are doing something such as:

```
select * from somewhere;
select id from somewhere;
select names from somewhere;
```

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp

Notice how you must store the first result, then call mysqli_next_result() to fetch the next results. It's throwing them all in 1 batch and returning them all back at you.

EDIT: Marc B is correct in the comment where you are technically using 2 statements by setting the row. In that case you are using multiple queries. I didn't see that at first.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` indeed cannot execute your given queries.

If you want to use `mysqli_multi_query`, then you can do the following

```
$mysqli->multi_query(ABOVE_STATEMENT);
$mysqli->next_result(); # skip the first query result
$rs = $mysqli->store_result();
while ($row = $rs->fetch_row()) {
  ...
}
```